# Why are Linux kernel packages priority set to optional?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

Why do the `linux-image` kernel packages have their priority in `apt`/`dpkg` set as `optional` rather than `important` or `required`?

```
$ apt show linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic
Package: linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic
Version: 5.4.0-26.30
Built-Using: linux (= 5.4.0-26.30)
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
```

```
root@luoyaoming:~# apt showsrc linux                    
Package: linux
Format: 1.0
Binary: *
Architecture: all amd64 armhf arm64 ppc64el s390x i386
Version: 5.4.0-26.30
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
```

Comment: because those do not need to be important or required.

Comment: Because you only need *a* kernel image, which can be satisfied by installing any *one* of them. Which means that any installed kernel images other than the one currently running are not necessary for the system's functioning.

Answer (score 15):

I believe this is because any single kernel package (or *line* of kernel packages) isn't required - simply because you can choose from a number of different kernel packages to suit your needs.

On Ubuntu 22.04 for instance, you can freely choose from the following *lines* of kernel packages:

- [linux-image-generic](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+package/linux-image-generic)
- [linux-image-lowlatency](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+package/linux-image-lowlatency)
- [linux-image-oem-22.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+package/linux-image-oem-22.04)
- [linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+package/linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04)

It should be noted that the above are metapackages, but the included kernel `image`, `headers` and `modules` all share the `optional` piority.

On top of this are different kernel images optimized for various cloud platforms - and maybe a bunch of other flavors as well.

Neither of these specific kernel images are *required* - but for the system to function, you need to choose at least *one of them* that you want to run.

Another possibility is that you have compiled your own kernel - and in this case it's also not at all required to have a kernel package installed.

More information about the priority levels are found in the [Debian Packaging Documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/pkg-basics.en.html#priority).

> #### 7.7. What is an Essential, Required, Important, Standard, Optional, or Extra package?
>
> Each Debian package is assigned a priority by the distribution
> maintainers, as an aid to the package management system. The
> priorities are:
>
> - **Required**: packages that are necessary for the proper functioning of the system.
>
>   This includes all tools that are necessary to repair system defects. You must not remove these packages or your system may become
>   totally broken and you may probably not even be able to use dpkg to
>   put things back. Systems with only the Required packages are probably
>   unusable, but they do have enough functionality to allow the sysadmin
>   to boot and install more software.
> - **Important** packages should be found on any Unix-like system.
>
>   Other packages which the system will not run well or be usable without will be here. This does NOT include Emacs or X or TeX or any
>   other large application. These packages only constitute the bare
>   infrastructure.
> - **Standard** packages are standard on any Linux system, including a reasonably small but not too limited character-mode system. Tools
>   are included to be able to send e-mail (with mutt) and download files
>   from archive servers.
>
>   This is what will be installed by default if users do not select anything else. It does not include many large applications, but it
>   does include the Python interpreter and some server software like
>   OpenSSH (for remote administration) and Exim (for mail delivery,
>   although it can be configured for local delivery only). It also
>   includes some common generic documentation that most users will find
>   helpful.
> - **Optional** packages include all those that you might reasonably want to install if you do not know what they are, or that do not have
>   specialized requirements.
>
>   This includes X, a full TeX distribution, and lots of applications.
> - **Extra**: packages that either conflict with others with higher priorities, are only likely to be useful if you already know what they
>   are, or have specialized requirements that make them unsuitable for
>   "Optional".
>
> If you do a default Debian installation all the packages of priority
> **Standard** or higher will be installed in your system. If you select pre-defined tasks you will get lower priority packages too.
>
> Additionally, some packages are marked as **Essential** since they are
> absolutely necessary for the proper functioning of the system. The
> package management tools will refuse to remove these.

From what I can see, it wouldn't make any difference in `apt` functionality if a package is of `optional`, `standard` or `important` priority. In the end, packages that are not part of a core Linux system will almost always be `optional` or `extra`.

*If anyone have qualified comments or opinions on this, please let me know in the comment section.*

Comment: This may be correct. But a couple of comments. 1) You mentioned meta-packages, not real kernel images. These are different and are not required for sure. 20 If you build your own kernel, you are the person who sets that priority ;-)

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to find out how this field is used by dpkg... If it doesn't let to remove required packages without some additional switch, then it makes sense to set them optional.

Comment: +1: "*Neither of these specific kernel images are required - but for the system to function, you need to choose at least one of them that you want to run.*" Well said.

Comment: Actually, depending on the system, you may not need to choose a kernel package at all. The most common example these days is a container, but other examples include a prefixed install for use with chroot, or certain types of virtual machine setups (where the host provides the kernel).

Comment: "Another possibility is that you have compiled your own kernel - and in this case it's also not at all required to have a kernel package installed." - isn't this true of (literally) every package?

Answer (score 12):

Ubuntu could run in a virtual machine where the kernel is provided at boot time by the host. Or it could run in a container like chroot, LXC or Docker, in which case it is using the host's kernel and does not need its own